# Picking out only values that match a number from a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, csv, import-from-csv

I have created a file that contains all data from my company as a CSV folder with a list.

The folder reads Name, Age, Join Year, Exit Year as the columns and looks like this:

```
Name, Age, Join Year, Exit Year
Mark , 19 , 2001      na 
Mike,  30 , 2000      na
```

I'm trying to isolate everyone who started in 2000. So far my code reads

```
import csv

with open('Confidential.csv', 'rU') as input: 
    dL= list(csv.reader(input))
    sL = dL
    print sL[2]
```

and this prints out all mikes data because i know that this is the line number in the `dL`.

What I want to know is there a simpler way of displaying everyone from 2000. Like is there a code that I can write to search for anyone who started in 2000 and if so can it then display the data in the line for those people.

i.e.

```
if raw_input = 2000
find all 2000 
print line data for any  line that contains 2000?
Like mike, 30, 2000, na because that matches 2000 :)
```

Is this possible or am I better to stick with the original code and typing each persons line number in individually?

Comment: Please add [python] tag to your question.

Answer (score 2):

`print filter(lambda xs:xs[2]==raw_input(), sL);`

This is what you are looking for i suppose.

Remainder: map(), filter() and any other method that uses functional programming paradigm does not have side effects. In other words, always catch the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter lists quite easily in python using the `filter` built in function. In your case, try this:

```
import csv

def started_in_2000(person):
    return person[2] == '2000'

with open('Confidential.csv', 'rU') as input: 

    all_people= list(csv.reader(input))

    people_who_started_in_2000 = filter(started_in_2000, all_people)

    for person in people_who_started_in_2000:
        print person
```

`filter` takes two arguments: a list, and a function that returns true or false when passed items from the list. In this case, I made a function that returns true when a person started in 2000, and filtered the list of people using that function.

For more information on filter, check out the python documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on doing some more queries on the data, it might be better to convert it into a database.

Python is compatible with [`sqlite`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), which is a database that doesn't need a server and runs from a simple file. You can think of it like a CSV with advanced features.

So, here is the SQlite way:

```
import csv
import sqlite3  # This imports the drivers for sqlite that come with Python

database_file = 'employees.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(database_file)  # Creates a new database, or
                                       # opens a connection to the file
                                       # if it already exists

cur = conn.cursor()  #  A cursor, that we use to execute queries

q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees (Name, Age, JoinYear, ExitYear);"
cur.execute(q)  # Creates a new Employees table if it doesn't exist

with open('Confidential.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        q = """INSERT INTO Employees
                  (Name, Age, JoinYear, ExitYear)
               VALUES (?,?,?,?);"""
        cur.execute(q,row)
        conn.commit()

# Now we can do stuff like this

q = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE JoinYear = 2000;"
for result in cur.execute(q):
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(*result)
```

Not only that, suppose you want to find out all employees less than 30 years old?

```
q = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Age < 30;"
```

All "Jim"s:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'Jim';"
```

How many employees joined each year?

```
q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total', Year FROM Employees GROUP BY Year;"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best module to do these kind of manipulations is `pandas`. You can find a very short introduction at [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

For your problem the solution is as simple as

```
In [1]: import pandas
In [2]: data = pandas.read_csv('Confidential.csv', delimiter=',', na_values=['na'], skipinitialspace=True)
In [3]: data     # printing the read data
Out[3]: 
           Name    Age  Join Year  Exit Year
        0  Mark    19       2001        NaN
        1  Mike    30       2000        NaN

In [3]: data[data['Join Year'] > 2000]   # slicing the required data 
Out[3]: 
           Name    Age  Join Year  Exit Year
        0  Mark    19       2001        NaN
```